# Magento display tiered pricing for each product on cart page

Tags: checkout, cart, price, tierprice

I am having an issue getting the `tierPriceHtml` to display for each item on the cart page.

This is what I have inside `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`:

```
$custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$tierPrice = $custom->getTierPriceHtml();
echo $tierPrice;
```

However this will not echo out anything. I also tried this with no luck:

```
echo $this->getTierPriceHtml()
```

How can I do this? Should I do something to modify the checkout.xml file in order to display it?

Here is my entire checkout/cart/item/default.phtml file:

http://pastebin.com/4wK2P9zU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to display the tiered pricing for each cart item on the cart view page, it might be worth clarifying this in your question.

It looks like you are trying to call the method `getTierPrice()` from the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class instead of the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` class.

You could create your own custom block that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` but the easiest way to achieve what you want is to create a new instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` for each item.

**Add this after `$_item = $this->getItem();` inside checkout/cart/item/default.phtml:**

```
$_tierPricing = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'catalog/product_view',
    'product.tierprices',
    array(
        'product_id' => $_item->getProductId()
    )
);
$_tierPricing->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml');
```

And then where you want to put your pricing info:

```
<?php echo $_tierPricing->getTierPriceHtml();?>
```

1. On the first line we create a new product view block and pass in the products' ID. **It is important this is done now during the creation phase rather after the block is instantiated to avoid errors in the _prepareLayout method.**
2. Then we set the tiered pricing template, you should probably make a new template used just for the cart. Perhaps `checkout/cart/item/tierprices.phtml`
3. Now we can use the getTierPriceHtml() method successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just tried this but this did not work either. It still is not outputting the results. The product has tier pricing and cache is off and I even flushed it.

Comment: No worries! Are you sure you're adding it to the correct template file? i.e. it's not being overridden by another file somewhere? can you echo out "hello world" where the tiered prices are supposed to go?

Comment: I've just tested this on a blank installation of Magento and it definitely works, I hope you can figure out what's going on!

Comment: thank you for confirming it works on a new installation. That lets me know it has something to do with the original developers coding. I was starting to think I was going crazy lol. I'll compare the file with an orignial and etc. I'll mark you answer correct since you went through the trouble to confirm it working. I will also post an update above with the file I am trying to get it working on and maybe you can spot the issue for me. P.S. I used the template path hints so it is the correct file. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm only posting the top half of the file since it is long ;)

Comment: Hey I've edited the question slightly, see what you think? Can you just paste the whole default.phtml in http://pastebin.com/ and link it here in the comments? I'll try it out on my system and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Pasted that in and it worked fine, the problem must be occurring somewhere else!

Comment: Ok thanks! Yah I have run across many odd issues like this one including not being able to set a static block as a category. The old developer did some very weird things. Thanks for confirming this!

Comment: I used your code but i find that it only works if the first product in the cart has a tier price however it then prints the tier price on all other products below (even if they dont have a tier price) any reason why this could be happening?

Comment: You have to give the product to the `getTierPriceHtml` call. See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/showing-if-a-product-has-a-tier-price/56008#56008 for the full answer.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get an array of tiered prices for the product like this:

```
$custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
var_dump($custom->getTierPrice());
```

With this you could format the array into something easily readable.  Here is sample output from my demo:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
["price_id"]=>
string(2) "11"
["website_id"]=>
string(1) "0"
["all_groups"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cust_group"]=>
int(32000)
["price_qty"]=>
string(6) "5.0000"
["price"]=>
string(8) "599.0000"
["website_price"]=>
string(8) "599.0000"
 }
 [1]=>
array(7) {
["price_id"]=>
string(2) "12"
["website_id"]=>
string(1) "0"
["all_groups"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cust_group"]=>
int(32000)
["price_qty"]=>
string(7) "10.0000"
["price"]=>
string(8) "499.0000"
["website_price"]=>
string(8) "499.0000"
}
[2]=>
array(7) {
["price_id"]=>
string(2) "13"
["website_id"]=>
string(1) "0"
["all_groups"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cust_group"]=>
int(32000)
["price_qty"]=>
string(7) "15.0000"
["price"]=>
string(8) "399.0000"
 ["website_price"]=>
 string(8) "399.0000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I just tried this but it still didn't output anything. The html is still empty. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm going to try this out in a sandbox now

Comment: That didn't work either. I don't know why this is so hard lol. Thanks, I look forward to seeing your working results ;)

Comment: I wasn't able to get the Html version to render, but I was able to pull the tier pricing information.  This piqued my interest though and I think there must be a way to extend it to pull the html-formatted from the getTierPriceHtml() function.

Comment: I know. It has had me scratching my head all night lol.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation suggest by jharrison.au work but if you want to use another design for the tier price in the shopping cart you have to modify

```
$_tierPricing->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml');
```

for

```
$_tierPricing->setTierPriceTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml');
```

Thanks

Comment: What is $_tierPricing in this case?