# Get TierPrices on home page/outside product view

Tags: tierprice, home

I made a .phtml block which should display the lowest price by the parameter sku

```
{{block type="core/template" sku="theproductsku" template="getlowestprice.phtml"}}
```

and the getlowestprice.phtml looks like this

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->sku);
$price=$prod->getPrice();
```

While getting price works just fine, getting the tier price like I used in product view doesnt work:

```
$prices = $this->getTierPrices($_product);
```

($prices equals NULL)

Is there any workaround to get tier prices outside product view?

Comment: Question was already answered: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/magento-display-tiered-pricing-for-each-product-on-cart-page

Comment: doesnt work unfortunately, tried all answers, even getTierPricesHtml() does not work :(

Comment: **$custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->sku);
var_dump($custom->getTierPrice());**

Comment: @Charlie thank you worked perfectly, pls post as answer to get reward

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls. Sorry for Late reply, I am out for the weekend.

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls. Hey I am waiting for the my reward.

Comment: @Charlie u got it sry was away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->sku); var_dump($custom->getTierPrice());
```

Answer (score 6):

To simply get all the tier prices you could try the following:

```
$prices = $product->getFormatedTierPrice();
```

The reason your call for `$this->getTierPrices($_product);` is not working is because your block it not of a type that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` which contains this `getTierPrices` function.

What you could do would be to use this function would be to make your own block that extends this and then use that instead of `core/template`

Answer (score 2):

Create your own custom block

```
$_tierPricing = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'catalog/product_view',
    'product.tierprices',
    array(
        'product_id' => $yourproductId
    )
);
$_tierPricing->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml');

<?php echo $_tierPricing->getTierPriceHtml();?>
```