# Showing if a product has a Tier price

Tags: magento-1.9, tierprice

I am not sure if this is possible but i want to add something to my cart table that checks if a products has a tiered saving (Buy 2 and save £5) and if the customer is not taking advantage of this saving then it tells them so in the cart.

Ideally we would like to have a String saying "Saving available" then when you put your cursor over it it pops up with a box showing the tiered price. I have added a picture to show what i mean. 
[image]

However if that is not possible (the hover) is it possible just to show the saving in the cart under the title 
[image]

I have just tried this:

```
Add this after $_item = $this->getItem(); inside checkout/cart/item/default.phtml:

$_tierPricing = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'catalog/product_view',
    'product.tierprices',
    array(
        'product_id' => $_item->getProductId()
    )
);
$_tierPricing->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml');
And then where you want to put your pricing info:

<?php echo $_tierPricing->getTierPriceHtml();?>
```

Source:[Magento display tiered pricing for each product on cart page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/magento-display-tiered-pricing-for-each-product-on-cart-page)

And i can see it is pulling the template in but it is displaying nothing

////////////////UPDATE\\\\\\\\\
It seems to work it the product that is first in the cart has a tiered price but then it displays that tier price on all products??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted solution just needs a tiny improvement. So here is the full answer:

1. Copy the template `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` to your theme.
2. Add the following code after the line `$_item = $this->getItem();`:

   ```
   $_tierPricing = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
       'catalog/product_view',
       'product.tierprices',
       array(
           'product_id' => $_item->getProductId()
       )
   );
   ```
3. Add the following code where you want the tier price to be displayed:

   ```
   <?php echo $_tierPricing->getTierPriceHtml($_item->getProduct());?>
   ```