# Showing tier price on cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, tiered-pricing

I'm trying to display tier pricing on the cart page. I followed this: [Magento display tiered pricing for each product on cart page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/magento-display-tiered-pricing-for-each-product-on-cart-page)

It works but the thing is that, what every product is shown first in the cart i.e. the one on top position,  all the rest get the same tier pricing, it just repeats the first position tier price to any other products added to the cart.

What is making it repeat the tier price to the rest of the products and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your posted solution just needs a tiny improvement. So here is the full answer:

1. Copy the template `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` to your theme.
2. Add the following code after the line `$_item = $this->getItem();`:

   ```
   $_tierPricing = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
       'catalog/product_view',
       'product.tierprices',
       array(
           'product_id' => $_item->getProductId()
       )
   );
   ```
3. Add the following code where you want the tier price to be displayed:

   ```
   <?php echo $_tierPricing->getTierPriceHtml($_item->getProduct());?>
   ```

Comment: Your Welcome @Freejoy